# Font Awesome Blinking in Google Chrome

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, fonts, font-awesome

I am using FontAwesome as a few of my icons on my website:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.5.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
```

But, in chrome when I refresh the page it takes 0.5-ish second for Font Awesome to load causing the page to shift and then move back when the font is loaded.

I have tried it with Edge and Firefox and they load instantly, why is this?

Comment: google for "FOUT". If Chrome is faster at displaying your content before loading the CSS, you'll get a **F**lash **O**f **U**nstyled **T**ext, which is why you generally need to make sure to not have an entire DOM render before your CSS is done loading (and that the content you do show while CSS still loads doesn't really on too much styling). Where's the rest of your code? E.g. where is the HTML that shows how much of your content is using fontawesome?

Comment: I am using myBB and FA to load the Forum Icons and that is it. I am using it on maybe 1 thing which is 4 items.

Comment: Are the unstyled forum icon placeholders differently sized from what FA turns them into? If so, trying to match those up should (even with a the restyle) no longer cause content shifts.

Answer (score 2):

Try putting it directly on your hosting server and load it from there. Loading assets from CDNs sometimes causes issues.